# Holomorphic at infinity (definition)

Tags: complex-analysis

I struggle quite a bit with the usage of $\infty$ in complex analysis. In some cases, I can translate a definition involving infinity to equivalent statements using limits, or in the case of continuity I just make use of the topology defined on the Riemann sphere.

However, what I don't understand is why the notion of differentiability is defined at the point infinity. A function $f(z)$ is said to be holomorphic at $\infty$ if $f(1/z)$ is holomorphic at $z=0$. Same can be said about singularities. I just don't see why we would do this. For instance, when I'm asked to determine singularities, it often forget to check the point $\infty$, because the definition feels so arbitrary: yea, let's check this random point which is actually a limit, and then somehow that tells us something?

My source of confusion lies in the fact that I don't see why being holomorphic at $\infty$ tells us anything (well, I guess, besides that our function is bounded). I understand that being holomorphic around some complex number $a$ is useful, as we can then write our function as a power series around $a$, of in the case of isolated singularities, we can work with Laurent expansion. But we don't have these things when it comes down to $\infty$ (except when we switch to $f(1/z)$, but that's a whole different function now, no?)

I hope someone understands my confusion and could shed some light on this issue.

Comment: Perhaps start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere. See also Needham's [Visual Complex Analysis](http://usf.usfca.edu/vca/).

Comment: @Ihf I am familiar with what's written there. My question unfortunately still holds.

Comment: holomorphic at infinity means there is a power series in $1/z$ convergent on the outside of a disc of large radius and that can be quite useful; even having a pole at infinity is useful too

Comment: @Conrad Maybe I shouldn't have said I doubted its usefulness, but rather, why call it like that? We don't consider differentiability at infinity in real analysis either.

Comment: real-analysis is different than complex analysis in many ways - infinity in the plane is (almost) equivalent to any point conformally by using Mobius transforms and there is a lot of simplification and unification thinking that way - eg lines are circles that pass through $\infty$, there is a natural topology and a natural complex structure on the Riemann sphere (plane plus infinity) etc - none of these things have very good analogues on the line

Answer (score 3):

Very belated, but in the hope it's helpful to posterity:

If $U$ is a non-empty open subset of the complex plane, there is a well-defined condition for a complex-valued function $f$ in $U$ to be *holomorphic*, namely that the complex derivative
$$
f'(z_{0}) := \lim_{z \to z_{0}} \frac{f(z) - f(z_{0})}{z - z_{0}}
= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z_{0} + h) - f(z_{0})}{h}
$$
exists for every $z_{0}$ in $U$.

The basic idea of Riemann surfaces, or generally of [structures on manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694962/what-is-fundamentally-a-coordinate-system), is to extend concepts such as *holomorphic functions* in a coordinate-independent way.

For example, suppose we take two copies of the complex plane and identify an arbitrary non-zero complex number $z$ in one copy with the non-zero complex number $w = 1/z$ in the other copy. (Geometrically, the points $(z, 1)$ and $(1, w)$ lie on the same line through the origin, see *the projective line* below.) Because the complex reciprocal is holomorphic and bijective with holomorphic inverse (or *biholomorphic*) in the punctured plane, "$f(z)$ is holomorphic if and only if $f(w) = f(1/z)$ is holomorphic." (The quotes guard against fine print about domains, and the fact that really $f$ is holomorphic, not $f(z)$ or $f(w)$.)

The [modern perspective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447567/flag-manifold-to-complex-projective-line) is to take a disjoint union of two complex planes (labeled $V_{0}$ and $V_{1}$ in the linked diagram), impose the equivalence relation $z \sim w = 1/z$ as above, and to view the result as a topological space with the property that every point has a neighborhood modeled on an open set of the complex plane, and so that "holomorphic" is well-defined modulo the equivalence $\sim$. The resulting topological space has at least a few pleasant descriptions:

- The *extended plane*, namely the disjoint union of the complex $z$-plane with a single point where $w = 0$, which we interpret as $z = \infty$.
- The *Riemann sphere*, viewed as the one-point compactification of the plane via [stereographic projection](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1625422). (A [bit of care](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4252402/stereographic-projection-through-south-pole) is required to view the $w$-plane as the complement of $0$ in the sphere.)
- The *complex projective line*, i.e., the set of complex lines through $(0, 0)$ in $\mathbf{C}^{2}$, with the "non-vertical" line $w = mz$ corresponding to the complex number $m$, and the "vertical" line corresponding to $\infty$.

---

Now to the question: To check whether a function on an open subset of the sphere is holomorphic, we select a coordinate system $z$ or $w$, dictated by convenience if we're not at $z = 0$ ($w = \infty$) or $z = \infty$ ($w = 0$) and by necessity otherwise, represent our function in that coordinate, and ask if the resulting representation is holomorphic. Thanks to the biholomorphism between the overlapping parts of the $z$-plane and $w$-plane, the answer is well-defined (independent of the choice of coordinate).

You're right that $f(z)$ and $f(1/z)$ are different functions. On the other hand, if we identify $w = 1/z$, then modulo domain issues we can define a function $g$ by $g(w) = g(1/z) = f(z)$, and *those* are "the same."

Why is this useful? For one thing, it allows us to do complex analysis near $\infty$, and generally on a compact, boundaryless domain. It turns out that holomorphic functions on the sphere are uninteresting (because they're all constant; why?), but meromorphic functions and $1$-forms, and generally "holomorphic objects with isolated singularities," not only remain interesting, but naturally guide us into topology of surfaces.

To give a few representative examples:

- A non-constant polynomial function is meromorphic, with a pole at $\infty$ of order equal to the degree. For example, $1 + z^{2} = 1 + (1/w)^{2} = (w^{2} + 1)/w^{2}$ has a double pole at $z = \infty$.
- The entire function $\exp$ is not meromorphic, but has an essential singularity at $z = \infty$ because $\exp(1/w)$ has an essential singularity at $w = 0$.
- The meromorphic $1$-form $dz/z = -dw/w$ has simple poles at $0$ and $\infty$, and the sum of the residues is $0$, but has a non-meromorphic primitive, $\log$ viewed as a multi-valued function on the set of non-zero complex numbers. Integrating this $1$-form defines a topological covering map that turns out to be the universal cover of the punctured plane.

Comment: Hi, I was thinking about exactly this earlier today. Is there a differential-geometric structure on some kind, on the complex plane, that allows the derivative $f'(\infty)$ to be defined (and thus, analyticity to be defined) *without* passing to $z\mapsto1/z$? (I ask as someone who has studied neither differential geometry nor advanced complex analysis)

Comment: @FShrike Briefly "no." But then, using the reciprocal to introduce coordinates at $\infty$ is as pleasant (simple, natural, explicit, ...) a technique as one could hope for, and the result (the sphere, with its rich transitive groups of symmetries--rotations, and conformal transformations) emphatically justifies doing so.

Comment: Ok, good to know. Thanks for the response