# Stereographic Projection Through South Pole

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, stereographic-projections, riemann-sphere

I am trying to find the map:

$$\psi_2(u,w,v):\mathbb{S}^2\smallsetminus\{0,0,-1\}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$$

So this is what I have done, let $(u,v,w)$ be a point on the sphere, and let $(0,0,-1)$ be the south pole. The line between these two points can be given by:

$$\mathbf{r}(t)=(u,v,w)t+(1-t)(0,0,-1)$$
$$=(tu,tv,tw-1+t)$$
Now if I want to find the point on the plane $z=0$ I have to have:
$$tw-1+t=0$$
$$\Rightarrow t=\frac{1}{1+w}$$
Which then gives:
$$(x,y)=(\frac{u}{1+w},\frac{v}{1+w})$$
Which can be associated with the complex number:
$$z=\frac{u}{1+w}+i\frac{v}{1+w}$$
However wikipedia says that his map should be:
$$\psi(u,v,w)=\frac{u}{1+w}-i\frac{v}{1+w}$$
And I can't figure out where I went wrong. When I did the same thing for the northpole projection I got exactly the result that wikipedia got. So where am I going wrong?

Comment: You're right. The stereographic projection of $(u, v, w)$ should be $\frac{u}{1 + w} + i \frac{v}{1 + w}$, from the south pole. The sign change of $v$ makes no sense geometrically speaking.

Comment: I’m not right though because you need the minus sign to make the diffeo between $\mathbb{CP}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^2$ to work. Wikipedia says something about an orientation switch to make sure the sphere is adequately covered by the 2 projections but that doesn’t really make sense to me

Comment: Yes, Wikipedia is right about the orientation switch. Let me try to explain why. Let us say that the sphere is oriented with a normal unit vector field pointing inwards. If you do a stereographic projection from the North pole onto say the equatorial plane, then this mapping is orientation-preserving if you orient the equatorial plane with a normal unit vector field pointing in the positive z-direction.

Comment: On the other hand, if you do a stereographic projection from the South pole, and assuming you are using an inward normal unit vector field on the sphere again, then this mapping is orientation-preserving if you use the orientation given by the unit normal vector field on the equatorial plane pointing in the negative z-direction. So if you wish to use a chart which is compatible with the orientation, you need to use opposite orientations on the equatorial plane for the 2 stereographic projections.

Comment: @Christopher Oh I see. I'm too used to working with stereographic projection in the real context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't gone wrong, calculation-wise. The problem, as you've identified, is that the two stereographic projection mappings from the north and south poles are not holomorphically compatible; their composition is inversion in the unit circle,
$$
z \mapsto \frac{z}{|z|^{2}} = \frac{1}{\bar{z}},
$$
rather than the desired complex reciprocal map. If we take stereographic projection from the north pole as one local holomorphic chart, then the *complex conjugate* of stereographic projection from the south pole is holomorphically compatible, however.