# $S^2$ with the two stereographic projections is a Riemannian surface.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Consider $S^2$ with the two stereographic projections obtained by removing respectively the North pole and the South pole, find the gluing function obtained through the definition of Riemannian surface with the two charts given by the two projections.

We call $\varphi_1$ the stereographic projection from $S^2- \{N \}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ and $\varphi_2$ the stereographic projection from $S^2- \{S\}$ to $\mathbb{C}$. We assume that the gluing map is defined by $(\varphi_1)^{-1} \circ \varphi_2: \mathbb{C}^* \to \mathbb{C}^*$. However, considering $z=x+iy \in \mathbb{C}^*$, recalling that $(\varphi_1)^{-1}(x,y)=(\frac{2x}{1+x^2+y^2},\frac{2y}{1+x^2+y^2},\frac{-1+x^2+y^2}{1+x^2+y^2})$ and $\varphi_2(x,y,z)=(\frac{x}{z+1},\frac{y}{z+1})$, we have $(\varphi_1)^{-1} \circ \varphi_2 (z)=(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2},\frac{y}{x^2+y^2})=\frac{z}{|z|^2}=\frac{1}{\bar z}$. However, as I have seen in other parts, the result should be $\frac{1}{z}$. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost a duplicate to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4252402/stereographic-projection-through-south-pole) post but I think it is worth going through some details.
Not least because of notation.

In [this notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection#First_formulation)  $(x,y,z)$ are Cartesian coordinates on the sphere, and $(X,Y)$ on the plane. The projection from the north pole and its inverse are
\begin{align}
\pi_N(x,y,z)=(X,Y)&=\left(\frac{x}{1-z},\frac{y}{1-z}\right)\,,\\
\pi^{-1}_N(X,Y)=(x,y,z)&=\left(\frac{2X}{1+X^2+Y^2}\,,\frac{2Y}{1+X^2+Y^2}\,,\frac{-1+X^2+Y^2}{1+X^2+Y^2}\right)\,.
\end{align}
Checking $\pi_N\circ\pi^{-1}_N$:
\begin{align}
1-z&=\frac{2}{1+X^2+Y^2}\,,&
\frac{x}{1-z}&=X\,,&\frac{y}{1-z}&=Y
\end{align}
as it should.
According to Andrew D. Hwang's hint in his [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4252402/stereographic-projection-through-south-pole/4252521#4252521) we have to take the *complex conjugate* projection from the south pole. This and its inverse are
\begin{align}
\pi_S(x,y,z)=(X,Y)&=\left(\frac{x}{1+z},\frac{-y}{1+z}\right)\,,\\
\pi^{-1}_S(X,Y)=(x,y,z)&=\left(\frac{2X}{1+X^2+Y^2}\,,\frac{-2Y}{1+X^2+Y^2}\,,\frac{1-X^2-Y^2}{1+X^2+Y^2}\right)\,.
\end{align}
Complex numbers should now be denoted as $X+iY$ and not by the
Cartesian coordinate $z\,.$ To get
$$
X+iY\mapsto \frac{1}{X+iY}=\frac{X-iY}{X^2+Y^2}
$$
we have to compose $\pi_N\circ\pi^{-1}_{\color{red}{S}}\,:$
$$
1-z=1-\frac{1-X^2-Y^2}{1+X^2+Y^2}=\frac{2X^2+2Y^2}{1+X^2+Y^2}
$$
leads to the expected complex inverse of $X+iY\,:$
$$
\pi_N\circ\pi^{-1}_{\color{red}{S}}(X,Y)=\left(\frac{X}{X^2+Y^2},\frac{-Y}{X^2+Y^2}\right)\,.
$$

Comment: So the inverse of the projection from the south pole is $( \frac{x}{z+1}, -\frac{y}{z+1})$ , thx

Comment: We could have not put a minus sign in front of $y$ and $Y$. With the minus sign we have the *complex conjugate* and its inverse.

Comment: and why put we a minus signto have the complex conjugate?  (maybe beacuse we are in $\mathbb{C}$?)

Comment: $(X,Y)$ is a complex number. Yes. BTW your attempt in OP produced (abuse of notation) $z\mapsto \frac1{\bar{z}}\,.$ In a way it is not surprising that conjugating $\pi_S$ leads to the desired $z\mapsto \frac1z\,.$

Comment: Ok, thanks very much